# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3346 in java.library.path

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-me

I trying to run a j2me project by KEmulator with Elipse + MJT + Jave_ME_SDK_3.0  in Mac OS ,  it display an error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3346 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at emulator.i.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at emulator.ui.swt.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at emulator.Emulator.main(Unknown Source)
```

The project is success to run on Windows system ,How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That error suggests it is not able to find the SWT native Windows libraries. Given that you are using MacOS I'm not sure what good they would be anyway. Perhaps the emulator uses them?

The libraries are bundled into the Windows version of SWT. Do you have an swt.jar on your classpath? What happens if you try running with the Windows version from: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/

Comment: It can invoking the Kemulator.jar to run the project in Windows version.

Comment: I am not sure how to add swt.jar to the class path under Mac OS.

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: add the application as an external jar on the J2me project setting, and set the default emulator to this application.

Comment: Try adding the swt jar as an external jar as well.